# MVC @Html.RadioButtonfor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have 2 radio button and after valdidation failed from "Submit" button.The gender value (typeof `string`) was not selected according to previous selection.

```
Male @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.gender)
Female @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.gender)
```

Neither radio button is selected, while all my other textbox retain it's value except for gender

Comment: Your not setting any value for the radio buttons. What is typeof property `gender` (`string` or `enum`) and what are the possible values (just "Male" and "Female")?

Comment: it was string and strange thing is that now the value is set after i off and on visual studio.

Answer (score 3):

You are not setting a `value` attribute for the radio buttons. If they do not have a `value`, the speciications state that "on" is posted, and in your controller method, your model will be bound with `gender = "on"`. When you return the view, none of your radio buttons match `"on"` and so none are selected.

Change your view to add a value for the radio buttons

```
<label>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.gender, "Male", new { id = "" })
    <span>Male</span>
</label>
<label>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.gender, "Female", new { id = "" })
    <span>Female</span>
</label>
```

Note the `<label>` element means the user can click on the associated text to select a button, and the `new { id = "" }` removes the `id` attribute which would otherwise be creating invalid html (duplicate `id` attributes).

In addition, you should consider using an `enum` for the property rather than `string`

```
public enum Gender
{
    Male,
    Female
}
```

so the property is

```
public Gender Gender { get; set; }
```

and in the view (assumes you have included a using statement for the enum)

```
<label>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Gender, Gender.Male, new { id = "" })
    <span>@Gender.Male</span>
</label>
```

---

[link to specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-input-value-default-on) (for radio buttons and checkboxes)

> default/on
>
> On getting, if the element has a value attribute, it must return that attribute's value; otherwise, **it must return the string "on"**. On setting, it must set the element's value attribute to the new value.